# Increase JAVA square size

Tags: java, swing, size, paintcomponent

Good afternoon, i needs help, I wanted to increase the size of the square, when I use the angle 0 and 270 it works normally, but when the word is with the angle 90 and 180 when it increases with the mouse it does not respect the rule, follow the data on the panel

Angle: 0

[image]

Angle 90

[image]

Code here:

```
      txtpn1 = new JEditorPane() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                int angle = txtpn[0];  //Angulo 0,90,180,270 
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                AffineTransform aT = g2.getTransform();
                Shape oldshape = g2.getClip();
                double x = getWidth() / 2.0;
                double y = getHeight() / 2.0;
                aT.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y);
                g2.setTransform(aT);
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }

        txtpn1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
                arrastarObejto(txtpn1, arg0);
        }
    }
    public void arrastarObejto(JComponent component, MouseEvent e) {
        if (component.getCursor().getType() != 11 && component.getCursor().getType() != 9) {
            component.setLocation(component.getLocation().x + e.getX(), component.getLocation().y + e.getY());
        }

        if (component.getCursor().getType() == 11 || component.getCursor().getType() == 9) {
            component.setSize(e.getX(), e.getY()); //Here is the error
       }
   }
```

Simple code, where I can't stretch the square when it's at angle 90

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class help extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    help frame = new help();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public help() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblCorrect = new JLabel("Correct"){


            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                int angle = 0;
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                AffineTransform aT = g2.getTransform();
                //Shape oldshape = g2.getClip();
                double x = getWidth() / 2.0;
                double y = getHeight() / 2.0;
                aT.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y);
//                  g2.transform(aT);
                g2.setTransform(aT);
                //g2.setClip(oldshape);
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }


        };
        lblCorrect.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
                lblCorrect.setSize(arg0.getX(),arg0.getY());
            }
        });
        lblCorrect.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        lblCorrect.setBounds(48, 100, 74, 51);
        contentPane.add(lblCorrect);

        JLabel lblWrong = new JLabel("Wrong"){


            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                int angle = 90;
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                AffineTransform aT = g2.getTransform();
                //Shape oldshape = g2.getClip();
                double x = getWidth() / 2.0;
                double y = getHeight() / 2.0;
                aT.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y);
//                  g2.transform(aT);
                g2.setTransform(aT);
                //g2.setClip(oldshape);
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }


        };
        lblWrong.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                lblWrong.setSize(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        });
        lblWrong.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        lblWrong.setBounds(239, 100, 74, 51);
        contentPane.add(lblWrong);
    }
}
```

[image]

Other code:

```
package teste;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
public class help extends JFrame {
   public help() {
      setTitle("Rotate JLabel");
      JLabel label = new RotateLabel("TutorialsPoint");
      add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setSize(400, 300);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);
      label.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
      label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            label.setSize(e.getX(),e.getY());

        }
    });
   }
   private class RotateLabel extends JLabel {
      public RotateLabel(String text) {
         super(text);
         Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC, 10);
         FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font){};
         Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, null);
         setBounds(0, 0, (int) bounds.getWidth(), (int) bounds.getHeight());
      }
      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         Graphics2D gx = (Graphics2D) g;
         gx.rotate(Math.PI/2, getX() + getWidth()/2, getY() + getHeight()/2);
         super.paintComponent(g);
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new help();
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post [mre]

Comment: I added a simpler code to be analyzed

Comment: See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-we-rotate-a-jlabel-text-in-java

Comment: It remains the same, I stretch it downwards and the square stretches upwards